# Initializing singleton properties, in init or in sharedMyClass?

Tags: coding-standards, objective-c

So I have a singleton in Objective-C, there's one static method exposed to access the one and only instance:

```
+ (id)sharedMyClass {
    static MyClass* sharedMyClass = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedMyClass = [[self alloc] init];
        sharedMyClass.myStringProperty = @"bla"; // here
    });
    return sharedMyClass;
}
```

and a non-exposed `init` method, used only when the instance is first created:

```
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.myStringProperty = @"bla"; // or here
        return self;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

I can initialize the instance's properties in the first method, by setting them directly on `sharedMyClass` within the `dispatch_once` block. Or I can set them on `self` in the `init` method. I know functionally there isn't any difference, but is there a convention for this? What's the best practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting them in `-init` is better. You might someday wish to make this a non-singleton (for example, scoped to user session), or a "hybrid" singleton (`NSUserDefaults` has a "singleton-like" member but you can also create arbitrary instances). If setup is done in `-init`, you won't need to change as much for this.

Answer (score 0):

I always initialise them in the +shared method. And then it gets more and more and I add an -init method and kick myself because I should have done that in the first place. Either do it like me, or better start with the init method in the first place.